# OpenCV defining a pattern

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Ineed to create a program that can detect the snooker ball's number.

Now I read a little about Open CV and i understand it might be able to do the job.

So before i waste my time learning it, I want to make sure that something like that is possible with open cv, doest anyone with open cv knowlege knows if this kind of thing is possible.

[image: ball]

Also i tryed using cvFindContours, and what i got is:

[image]

How can i detect a certain pattern? any refference would be appreciated

Comment: "So before i waste my time learning it" Learning is never a waste off time! And yes, you could to the job with openCV if you first learn some basics in image processing so you can decide which tools might do the best job for you.

Comment: too many things to learn in this world, you should be picky on which to waste your time on. thx for the answer, I will make some more research

Comment: type _'introduction to pattern recognition'_ to google search bar..

Comment: I managed to do it, not that hard apperantly